# Why is my classloader throwing ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: java, reflection, jar, classpath

I have an abc.jar and I'm loading a class using reflection. But I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException. My code is as below:

```
File file1 = new File(ApplicationContext.getPath()+"lib/abc.jar");
            Class noparams[] = {};
            URL url = file1.toURI().toURL();
            URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
            cls = cl.loadClass("com.abcd.feat.udf.MobileUDF");
            Constructor<?> c = cls.getConstructor();
            mobileUDFActions = c.newInstance();
```

I have verified that the jar is present in ApplicationContext.getPath()/lib folder.

Contents of jar are appropriate. It contains classes in the package com/abcd/feat/udf.

Please help me realize what is the mistake. I'm getting below exception.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.abcd.feat.udf.MobileUDF
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at com.abcd.feat.core.TestScriptExecutor.<init>(TestScriptExecutor.java:85)
```

Comment: your classes under jar are public??

Comment: Show the complete stacktrace please.

Comment: Print file1 and url and tell us what their value is.

Comment: file1 is printing the path of the jar. I have checked that.
And url is printing the path of the file

Comment: If you don't want to cooperate, don't ask for help here. What does it cost you to provide what I ask, so that WE can make sure there isn't any problem with the paths? If you know better than us, why do you ask a question? Also, post the **complete** stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Go through this link. http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-classloader-works-in-java.html